# C++ explicit universal reference constructor does not hide copy constructor?

Tags: c++, c++11, copy-constructor, universal-reference

Probably my understanding of `explicit` is insufficient, but I wonder why in the following code the copy constructor is not hidden by the unversal reference constructor when I declare the latter as `explicit`.

```
struct A
{
    A() = default;

    template<typename T>
    A(T&& t) { std::cout<<"hides copy constructor"<<std::endl; }
};

struct A_explicit
{
    A_explicit() = default;

    template<typename T>
    explicit A_explicit(T&& t) {  std::cout<<"does not hide copy constructor?"<<std::endl; }
};

int main()
{
    A a;
    auto b = a; (void) b;  //prints "hides copy constructor"

    A_explicit a_exp;    
    auto b_exp = a_exp; (void) b_exp; //prints nothing
}
```

[DEMO](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/68c0f7e609cc7f81)

Is that a general solution instead of the SFINAE stuff one would apply otherwise to prevent the hiding in `A` (for example by `std::enable_if_t<!std::is_same<std::decay_t<T>, A>::value>`, see [here](https://akrzemi1.wordpress.com/2013/10/10/too-perfect-forwarding/))?

Comment: For those interested, [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/converting_constructor) is some explanation which I found based on the answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A constructor marked as `explicit` does not participate in overload resolution during copy-initialization (`A a = b;`, among other things).

It does participate in copy-list-initialization (`A a = {b1};`), and causes the program to be ill-formed if selected.

... except when the thing inside the braces is an `A` or a class derived therefrom, in which case a recent defect report changed the rules to say that in this particular situation copy-initialization is performed instead - and so `explicit` constructors are once again just ignored entirely ([demo](https://godbolt.org/z/1E4rdYxhc)).

Very teachable, I know.

> Is that a general solution instead of the SFINAE stuff one would apply
> otherwise to prevent the hiding in A?

No. Because that constructor will still win overload resolution for direct-initialization:

```
A_explicit a, b(a); // will call the constructor taking a forwarding reference
```

Answer (score 6):

In `A`, the copy constructor is **not hidden.** The compiler implicitly declares it, as it always does. It simply **loses overload resolution** because its parameter type (`const A&`) has extra cv-qualification compared to the parameter of the specialization of the constructor template (`A&`). If you would do

```
auto b = static_cast<const A&>(a);
```

you would see that the copy constructor would be called.

In `A_explicit`, the template is not submitted as a candidate to overload resolution at all, because it is declared `explicit`. The implicitly declared copy constructor is still there, like it is in `A`, so it is called.

Comment: thanks, but I didn't get the answer. Could you please explain a bit more in detail what happens when copying `A_explicit`? For example wht you mean by *the template is not submitted as a candidate to overload resolution at all*.

Comment: @davidhigh The function produced by instantiating the template has no chance of being called at all because the copy-initialization requires a non-explicit constructor. Whereas for `A` it's treated on equal footing with the copy constructor and the best match is chosen.